# How do I know when an app is available for update (alpha, beta or prod) in play store?

Tags: android, google-play

How do I know when an app is available for update (alpha, beta or prod) in play store? (We don't need this from the inside of the app) Is there any chance to get this info without the need to have a separate user for each stage (alpha, beta, prod) to view the play store listing?

We just want to have the information when the app has been published and is available for the users (for the given stage)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. One you could use this library to do  it.
   https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/Service
2. Or you can make a simple http request to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.namespace and parse the page for the version

`<div class="content" itemprop="softwareVersion"> 2.2.0  </div>`

Finally compare it in your app version in code

> String version = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;

Comment: Thanks, refined my question. We don't need this from inside the app. From the outside would be quite ok. The problem with your second suggestion is, that you either use only the prod stage listing of the app, or you need a user for each stage (alpha, beta, prod) to see if the update is really available for download

Comment: ha.. this i marketing stuff, One get notifications for updates only if they have installed the app which is also dependent of the playstore settings in one's phone. For alpha and beta i guess there is no notifications, you have to manually do it or add oneself as tester in developer console .

Comment: Btw. if you use alpha and beta, your second suggestion reveals: <div class="content" itemprop="softwareVersion">   Varies with device  </div>